# Render a tooltip under the anchor elements in Tiptap

Tags: reactjs, next.js, radix, tiptap, prose-mirror

I'm creating an editor with `Tiptap` and I'm struggling trying to implement a `notion-style` anchor element in my rich text editor.

Basically, I need to render a tooltip under the links with the href and an `edit link option`

Is there a way to render custom components for certain elements (`<a>` tags in this case)?

I'm getting the current hovered node this way, but now I can't figure out how to access that element and render the tooltip...

```
  const handleLinkHover = React.useCallback(
    (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
      if (!editor) return
      const target = event.target as HTMLElement
      const view = editor.view as EditorView
      const pos = view.posAtDOM(target, 0)

      if (pos === null || pos < 0) return

      const node = view.state.doc.nodeAt(pos)
      if (!node || !node.isAtom) return

      const linkMark = node.marks.filter((mark) => mark.type.name === 'link')

      if (linkMark.length > 0) {
        const href = linkMark[0]?.attrs.href
        const rect = target.getBoundingClientRect()

        setCurrentLinkTooltip({
          href,
          top: rect.top,
          left: rect.left,
        })
      } else {
        setCurrentLinkTooltip({
          href: null,
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
        })
      }
    },
    [editor]
  )
```

For `Tooltips` I'm using `Radix UI`

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We had this requirement in our application where we wanted to show a tooltip with button actions when a user clicks on a link.

Tiptap does something similar with the [Bubble Menu](https://tiptap.dev/api/extensions/bubble-menu). When text is selected in the editor, a tooltip with button actions appears on top of the selected text. I started digging-in the Tiptap's repo to see how Tiptap does it. Here are the details for Bubble Menu -

- Tiptap menus use [tippy.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tippy.js) for the tooltip, actions buttons are added in this tooltip component.
- A ProseMirror plugin adds this tooltip in the editor view - [BubbleMenuPlugin](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/develop/packages/extension-bubble-menu/src/bubble-menu-plugin.ts)
- This plugin is registered in the [BubbleMenu](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/develop/packages/react/src/BubbleMenu.tsx) component and [BubbleMenu](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/develop/packages/extension-bubble-menu/src/bubble-menu.ts) extension if you are using the extension.

That's it. I followed the exact same steps for implementing the action menu for links.

Here's the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2iqaet?file=package.json) with the working code. Notice that the `shouldShow` method is changed in the `LinkActionsPlugin.ts` to detect the cursor on links, you can use the same approach to open action menu tooltips on any node/ mark.